# MonacaのWebViewでGoogle Playストアのアプリへのリンクを開く方法

Tags: android, monaca, android-webview

初歩的な質問失礼しますm(__)m

Monacaでアプリを作成し、InAppBrowserのアプリ内ブラウザで外部サイトを表示させた時に、外部サイト内でGooglePlayアプリのリンクをクリックするとPC版のGooglePLAYストアが表示されてしまいます。

GooglePLAYアプリへのリンクをクリックした際に、GooglePLAYストアを表示させる方法はありますでしょうか？

お分かりの方がいらっしゃればご教授いただきたいですm(__)m

よろしくお願いします！

(現状)
Monaca内のindex.html内で外部サイトを表示

```
var ref = window.open('https://example.com/', '_blank', 'OPTIONS');
```

上記リンク先からGooglePLAYストアへ遷移した時にPC版のアプリページが表示される。

Comment: 初めから直接PlayストアのURLを指定した場合はどうなるのでしょうか？

Comment: アプリではなくweb版のGooglePLAYストアが表示されます。